# Is there a universal way to get LDAP Policy MaxPageSize value during LDAP session with AD?

Tags: active-directory, ldap

I'm using LDAP to get users from Active Directory domain controller, and I want to resolve `MaxPageSize` allowed to use it later.

There is a **difficult** [AD-specific mechanism](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/openspecs/windows_protocols/ms-adts/3f0137a1-63df-400c-bf97-e1040f055a99) to get actual `MaxPageSize` policy value for specific domain controller.

Is there is any mechanism to get `MaxPageSize` policy for current established LDAP connection, except guessing? I expect to get some kind of *virtual* object like `RootDSE` from DC or something.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no need to know current value of `MaxPageSize` for DC when using paged requests.

Passing `PageResultRequestControl` (`1.2.840.113556.1.4.319`) with value greater than DC's `MaxPageSize` value makes DC answer with pages of `MaxPageSize` records per page without any errors.

For Active Directory LDAP on Windows Server 2008 and newer, hardcoded limit is `20000`, so I can pass `20000` in request and I will get responses of maximum `MaxPageSize` entries in response.